# GE Refrigerator Fresh Food Evaporator Fan Always Running

Tags: refrigerator

GE refrigerator model# Gye22gencds French door fridge with bottom freezer purchased in 2020.

Freezer is cold but temperature in fresh food section fluctuates between 40-65°F. The fresh food evaporator fan is always running, even with doors open or in diagnostic mode. Is this normal?

I forced it into defrost and the fan was still running and blowing hot air into the fresh food section. This doesn't seem normal to me. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Fridge temps should be below 40 all the time.  I imagine a sensor or timer that controls the fan is broken.  See if you can search for a wiring diagram or repair manual for the make and model of the fridge.